# Step Builder pattern with two separate flows

Tags: java, builder

I am creating a builder class, where in i want to provide 2 flows to the user when creating by domain object.

My domain object looks like

```
public class Comparator<T> {
   private Map<String, ReflectionComparatorMode> includedFields;
   private List<String> excludedFields;
   private T expected;
   private T actual;
//getters
}
```

And my builder looks like

```
public static class ComparatorBuilder<T> {
    private Map<String, ReflectionComparatorMode> includedFields;
    private List<String> excludedFields;
    private T expected;
    private T actual;

    public ComparatorBuilder(T expected, T actual) {
        this.expected = expected;
        this.actual = actual;
        includedFields = new HashMap<String, ReflectionComparatorMode>();
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInStrictMode(String fieldName) {
        this.includedFields.put(fieldName, null);
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInStrictMode(List<String> fieldNames) {
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            this.includedFields.put(fieldName, null);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInLenientOrderMode(String fieldName) {
        this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInLenientOrderMode(List<String> fieldNames) {
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInLenientDateMode(String fieldName) {
        this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_DATES);
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInLenientDateMode(List<String> fieldNames) {
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_DATES);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInIgnoreDefaultMode(String fieldName) {
        this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS);
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> includeFieldsInIgnoreDefaultMode(List<String> fieldNames) {
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            this.includedFields.put(fieldName, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ComparatorBuilder<T> excludedFields(List<String> fieldNames) {
        this.excludedFields.addAll(fieldNames);
        return this;
    }

    public Comparator<T> build() {
        Comparator<T> comparator = new Comparator<T>();
        comparator.actual = this.actual;
        comparator.expected = this.expected;
        comparator.includedFields = this.includedFields;
        comparator.excludedFields = this.excludedFields;

        return comparator;
    }
```

Now i do not want the caller to be able to use excludedFields method if its calling any of the includedMethods(...) and similarly if its using excludedFields it should not be able to call any of the included methods. It should be able to directly call the build method.

How can this be achieved using builder pattern or step builder ?

Comment: It is unwise to choose a class name which the JDK already defines (`Comparator`)

Comment: Best way would be to make it a compilation error if the user tries to mix them.  That's best achieved by making ComparatorBuilder abstract, and moving the include and exclude methods to their own IncludeComoaratorBuilder and ExcludeComparatorBuilder classes that inherit from it.  Having said that, common behaviour when users can specify include and exclude criteria is to select based on the include, then remove those in the exclude.

Comment: My current use case is that we should be able to compare 2 objects by just specifying on the basis of fields i.e. offering a field by field creation. Now i want to provide user the ability to filter out some fields. So there doesnt seems to be a usecase for me where in would need to mix include n exclude.